# Changing CssClass based on bool in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have multiple `TemplateFields`, where each one contains two occurrences of `CssClass` that I want to changed based on a boolean `isGov` which is in the code-behind file.

As you can see below, I have an if/else statement in the .aspx file to change the text of a `label` in the `headertemplate` using the same `boolean` `isGov` that I want to use to change the `CssClass`. However, using the same concept did not work. I'm wondering what the correct way to do it is?

Here's the current code, the two `CssClass` that I'm trying to change are the last two:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SUN">
            <footertemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblD1F" runat="server" ForeColor="white" Width="35px" Text="<%# GetTotal(0).ToString() %>" />
            </footertemplate>
            <headertemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblD1H" runat="server" CssClass="hdr_Day" >
                <% if (isGov) { %> 
                MON
                <% } else { %>
                SUN
                <% } %>                 
                </asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblD1D" runat="server" CssClass="hdr_Date" Text='<%# _displayDate.ToString("MM/dd") %>'></asp:Label>                
            </headertemplate>
            <itemtemplate>
                <anthem:TextBox id="tbDay1" 
                                runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("Day1") %>'  
             ---> This one      CssClass="tbWeekEnd" 
                                AutoCallBack="true"  />
                <asp:Label ID="lblDay1" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("Day1") %>'></asp:Label>

            </itemtemplate>
            <itemstyle cssclass="cell_weekend" /> <--- And this one
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I also tried:

```
CssClass='<%# isGov ? "cell_weekday" : "cell_weekend" %>'
```

It doesn't seem like the boolean `isGov` is being recognized. Intellisense picks it up when I'm using the `if` statement, but not when trying to change the `CssClass`.

Edit: Basically what's happening is, a grid view contains some columns, 14 of which have a Date in the header column. The dates either start at Sunday or Monday based on the bool `isGov`, and a CssClass highlights the weekends. So I wanted to change the CssClass based on that bool as well, but only for the cells that fall under the weekend cells.

Comment: How is `isGov` defined in the code behind?

Comment: Simply `public bool isGov = false;`

Comment: And I see that it occurs one time in ItemStyle. Where is the other?

Comment: Sorry I should have marked it better, 5 lines above the `itemstyle`, in `<anthem:TextBox id="tbDay1" ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `ItemStyle` element cannot be initialized with data bound values. The proper way to do that would be to handle RowDataBound event of the GridView and set the class there:

```
protected void GridViewID_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // if you want the whole row class
        e.Row.CssClass = isGov ? "cell_weekday" : "cell_weekend";

        // if you want specific cell class
        e.Row.Cells[2] = isGov ? "cell_weekday" : "cell_weekend";
    }
}
```

Cell index is 0 based and corresponds to columns order defined in your markup.

As for the class of the TextBox, it should work fine the way you tried it with `<%# isGov ? ...`. But do no expect intellisense to help here - note that your are writing code inside a string, so from IDE perspective this is just a string value (unless some cool feature was built into recent versions of VS, which I did not hear of)

Comment: Yes, for the textbox it worked fine, like @TheRotag suggested in the other answer. For the answer you provided, wouldn't that change the whole row to a certain CssClass? I just need it to change for certain cells. I'll update my post on what it's being used for.

Comment: @pfinferno, oops, you are right, missed that. Added an example for specific cell class

Comment: Thank you! Will test it out now.

Comment: It isn't working exactly, but I'm pretty sure your way is correct.

Comment: I am pretty sure as well. What's the error?

Comment: The background color is changing to a plain white/grey when the `isGov` is true. When it's false, it correctly highlights it as green. This is strange because the "cell_weekday" doesn't contain a color, but yet the other cells that use it are correctly showing the color. I think what is happening is that the `textbox` in the cell is having it's own background color set apart from the cell.

Comment: Is there a way to access the textbox inside of the cell from code behind?

Comment: Wait, got it, it was referencing the wrong `cssClass`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, you can't set an attribute on a ASP.NET control (<asp:...>) using a server tag (<%...%>) within the attribute. Instead, you could add a line of code to set the CssClass property:

```
<% lblD1H.CssClass = isGov ? "cell_weekday" : "cell_weekend"; %>
```

Edit: if that doesn't work (on account of being in a template), you could always try plain HTML instead of an ASP label:

```
<label id="lblD1D" class='<%# isGov ? "cell_weekday" : "cell_weekend" %>'>
    <%# _displayDate.ToString("MM/dd") %>
</label>
```

Comment: The plain HTML seemed to work. However, the last cssClass, which is for an `itemstyle`, does not work with this for some reason.

Comment: Hmmm, no, I can see how it wouldn't work for `itemstyle`. For that, you'd probably need to set it in code behind, much like @Andrei suggested in his answer.

Comment: Okay thank you! Just curious, why doesn't it work for `itemstyle`?

Comment: @pfinferno, because ItemStyle is not data bound, so to say and it also is not a control property that you can operate in code behind. Which are the two options TheRotag suggested here.

Comment: It has to do with the page lifecycle and when server tags get rendered. If you have a server tag in HTML, it doesn't matter when that tag is evaluated, since it just gets plugged into HTML. However, if it's in an ASP control (or part of a control, like `itemstyle` is part of `<asp:TemplateField`), then that tag would have to be evaluated and its value plugged in to its parent control, which also has to be evaluated and rendered. Sadly, that doesn't work. I know that still leaves open the question of "But WHY doesn't it work", but sadly that's as much as I understand about it.

Comment: No that makes sense actually, thank you very much!